# Hibernate : failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, lazy-loading

I have two entities : User and Module wich are linked using the many-to-many .

in my User entity I have a Module list member :

[image]

I insert a new user successfully, but when I want to retrieve the Users I get the Users informations but I don't get the Modules of a user . and I get this error message :

.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ma.propar.FireApp.Entites.Utilisateur.modules, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Please paste a snippet of code !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `user.modules` `@ManyToMany` list is LAZY by default, so when you fetch `users` you only get a `user.modules` proxy.

If the Hibernate `Session` is closed, you won't be able to access the uninitialized proxies without getting a [`LazyInitializationException`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/).

To fetch modules in the same HQL query you need to use "fetch":

```
select u from Utilisateur u left join fetch u.modules
```

Although you can set the association to `FetchType.EAGER` so that you always retrieve modules along Users

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

you [shouldn't use EAGER because it's bad for performance](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).

Comment: What if I want to keep fetch type as eager, and I want to save data in PRIVILEGES table as I create a USER, I already have modules in Database.

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback on Vlad's answer, with annotations you can implement fetch with

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
```